# Reset the layout of vim after terminal resize

Tags: vim

If I have a vim / nvim session running and I resize the terminal then it messes up the layout and vim continues to act as if it was x columns wide.

Is there a command I can run for vim to refresh the layout and rerender with the updated column width.

Comment: Vim adjusts itself to changes in screen dimensions automatically so there is no need for the kind of command you are asking about. Instead, you should ask yourself why you get that unexpected behaviour. What terminal emulator? What `$TERM`? What OS? Etc.

Comment: @romainl Hmm I thought it did too. I am using windows terminal and powershell. `$TERM = vtpcon`. This is the current state: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aXc2Hf07d08

Comment: Well, that's not Vim but I guess it doesn't really matter because it looks a lot like a `$TERM` issue, something Windows Terminal has *a lot*. Try Neovim's issue tracker.

Answer (score 1):

You can press <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> to recalculate the splits based on the new terminal size.

See [`:help ctrl-w`](https://vimhelp.org/windows.txt.html#CTRL-W_%3D):

> `CTRL-W =`
>
> Make all windows (almost) equally high and wide, but use
> 'winheight' and 'winwidth' for the current window.
> Windows with 'winfixheight' set keep their height and windows
> with 'winfixwidth' set keep their width.

Answer (score -2):

It looks like you may have messed up terminal screen size. Try

```
CTRL + (+)
```

to Increase screen size and

```
CTRL-SHFT-(-)
```

to reduce screen size

Comment: to in crease you press CTRL and + together